# Why this C++ program is returning 16 bytes?

Tags: c++

The below program when compiled using gcc and executed on a 32-bit architecture returns 16 bytes. I am wondering why it is returning so as it is neither uses a long double member nor it is running on a 64-bit machine and there is no virtual functions defined to get extra bytes of memory and when calculating the size of **double** and **int** data member, the result comes around 12 bytes. So why this 16 bytes value?

```
class A {
public:
     void* data;
};
void* operator new (size_t sz, A& obj) {
     printf("Custom operator new called for %d bytes\n", sz);
     return obj.data;
}
class foo {
public:
     double a;
     int x;
     foo() { printf("foo constructor called (this=%p)\n", this); }
};
int main() {
     A obj;
     obj.data = malloc(sizeof(foo));
     printf("Allocator data: %p\n", obj.data); // Allocator data:  0x4601a8
     foo *f = new (obj) foo; // Custom operator new called for **16 bytes**
                                       // foo constructor called (this=0x4601a8)
     printf("foo allocated at %p\n", f); // foo allocated at 0x4601a8
}
```

Comment: There may be unnamed padding within a structure object

Comment: Depends on your default packing - with 1, 2 or 4 byte packing, you will get 12.  With 8 or 16 byte packing, you will get 16.

Answer (score 3):

`4` bytes are added at the end of `foo` as padding. This is typically done for alignment purposes - a `double` is aligned to `8` bytes on your architecture, so if you create an array of `foo`s, the padding bytes guarantee that the member `a` is properly aligned.

In a class-type **there's no guarantee that the size is equal to the sum of the sizes of members**. More often than not, it isn't.

There are special compiler-dependent flags that prevent padding bytes being added which you can look up. (`pragma pack`)

Answer (score 0):

There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, which is called [Data_structure_alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)

in your case, double is aligned to 8 bytes, so the sizeof foo should be 8*N ,so 4bytes padded

Answer (score 0):

when i run your code i found following :

```
class A {
public:
     void* data;
};
void* operator new (size_t sz, A& obj) {
     printf("Custom operator new called for %d bytes\n", sz);
     return obj.data;
}
class foo {
public:
     double a;
     int x;
     foo() { printf("foo constructor called (this=%p)\n", this); }
};
int main() {
     A obj;
     obj.data = malloc(sizeof(foo));
     printf("Allocator data: %p\n", obj.data); // Allocator data:  0x991d008
     printf("size of obj: %d\n", sizeof(obj)); // size of obj:  4
     printf("size of foo: %d\n",sizeof(foo)); // size of foo: 12
     foo *f = new (obj) foo; // Custom operator new called for **12 bytes**
                                       // foo constructor called (this=0x991d008)
     printf("foo allocated at %p\n", f); // foo allocated at 0x991d008
}
```

I have added two additional printing statement, here size of `foo` is 12. that is `double` + `int`.

Comment: Padding is system-specific so this is unfortunately not that helpful. The code will give different results on different computers and compilers.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of internal padding applied by the compiler. We can avoid this by using **__packed** compiler directive.

You can refer the following post for understanding about padding

[Structure padding and packing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-structure-packing)

Answer (score 0):

Consider [data alignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290049%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Compiler aligns data of the object in oder to store them in memory so that CPU can get them in one load - this is possible only for aligned data. This is hardware aspect.